# Can't get Hurricane Electric IPv6 tunnel to work on Fedora

Tags: fedora, ipv6

I have recently moved to a university where all computers get a public IPv4 address. Since the teredo tunnel I was using doesn't work anymore and I have a public address, I am wanting to use Hurricane Electric's tunnel broker service on my Fedora 15 Gnome machine.

I've already configured HE with my information and am just trying to get it working in Fedora. I'm using a modified configuration script from the [Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_setup_tunnel_broker_via_Hurricane_Electric) (which didn't work without modifications).

My `/etc/sysconfig/network` config:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=quackpad-fedora
NTPSERVERARGS=iburst
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=he-ipv6
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=2001:470:1f10:11d0::1/64   # Server IPv6 Address
```

And my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-he-ipv6`

```
DEVICE=he-ipv6
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes                         
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6TUNNELIPV4=209.51.181.2        # Server IPv4 address
IPV6TUNNELIPV4LOCAL=***.***.*.***  # My IPv4 address
IPV6ADDR=2001:470:1f10:11d0::2/64  # Client IPv6 address
```

If I do `sudo ifup he-ipv6` I get (why does ifup-eth care about that?)

```
 ERROR    : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Device he-ipv6 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
```

If I do `sudo service network restart`

```
Sep  1 18:15:07 quackpad-fedora NetworkManager[938]: <warn> connection /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1 failed to activate: (2) Device not managed by NetworkManager or unavailable
Sep  1 18:15:07 quackpad-fedora NetworkManager[938]: <warn> connection /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2 failed to activate: (2) Device not managed by NetworkManager or unavailable
Sep  1 18:15:08 quackpad-fedora /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth: Device he-ipv6 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
Sep  1 18:15:08 quackpad-fedora NetworkManager[938]: <warn> connection /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/0 failed to activate: (2) Device not managed by NetworkManager or unavailable
Sep  1 18:15:08 quackpad-fedora systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep  1 18:15:08 quackpad-fedora systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why do these keep failing?

Answer (score 2):

Add to ifcfg-he-ipv6:

```
TYPE=sit
```

And I think in the network file these lines are not necessary:

```
NETWORKING_IPV6=
IPV6INIT=
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=
```